# Compute the difference of observation counts between groups depending on the values the groups contain

Tags: r, list, count, max, lapply

I have the following two data frames in mylist. For each data frame, I would like to compute the difference between the number of observations of the group (identified by "type") that contains the maxiumum value ("value") and the number of observations of the other group.

So, for df1 this would be `3 - 6 = -3` since type B contains the maximum value of 7 and there are 3 observations for type B and 6 observations for type A.

```
value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7)
type  <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
df1   <- data.frame(value, type)

value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2)
type  <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
df2   <- data.frame(value, type)

mylist <- list(df1, df2)
```

I think it would be along the lines of the following in combination with `length(unique())` and `max()` but I can't figure it out.

```
calculation <- lapply(mylist, function (x) 
{x$#the count of observations of the type that includes the max value#) - (x$#the count of the observations of the type that does not include the max value)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick here is to see that your calculation can be simplified:

```
[number in group] - [number not in group]
= [number in group] - ([number of rows] - [number in group])
= [number in group] - [number of rows] + [number in group]
= 2 * [number in group] - [number of rows]
```

so you could do:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) {2*sum(x$type==x$type[which.max(x$value)])-nrow(x)})
```

which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] -3

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decompose

```
lapply(mylist, function(x){ 
  x[,"value"] <- as.numeric(x[,"value"])
  MAX_FLAG <- which(x[,"value"] == max(x[,"value"]))[1]
  MAX_FLAG <- x[MAX_FLAG,"type"]
  A <- length(which(x[,"type"] == "A" ))
  B <- length(which(x[,"type"] == "B" ))
  BA <- ifelse( MAX_FLAG == "B",B-A,A-B)
  return(BA)
 }
)
```

With a little adaptation you can have easily more than 2 groups (ie : A & B)

Hope it will help,

Gottavianoni

Answer (score 1):

You can also use aggregate to count the number of observations in each group:

```
calculations <- lapply(mylist, function(df) {
  sum_df <- aggregate(value~type, df, FUN = length)
  max_type <- df$type[which.max(df$value)]
  sum_df$value[sum_df$type == max_type] - sum_df$value[sum_df$type != max_type]
})
```